# What is the terminal command to install the whole gtk 3.14 libraries in ubuntu?

Tags: libraries, gtk3

I want to develop linux apps for ubuntu using C. Now, for that I need to install the gtk 3.14 libraries and the dependencies. I already tried to install it by downloading the libraries, but was not able to install due to some of the dependencies not being installed. How to install all the dependencies as well as the gtk 3.14 libraries using the single terminal command. Help!

Comment: Do you really need version 3.14 specifically? it will be a lot simpler if you can use the pre-packaged version for your distribution.

Comment: But where are the libraries installed, by the way?

Comment: Package `libgtk-3-dev` - development files for the GTK+ library

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is exactly what your looking for, but  might be of use. 
[gtk+3.0 Package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0)

Edit: it won't be a single command, but just click version you want for the distro you have and you will find a tarball that you can compile and install. There are even some .debs available too that might resolve your current dependency issue

Comment: Is there any command to install the packages as well as the required dependencies at the same time?